# Problems building a release .apk in react-native-maps

Tags: android, react-native, apk, react-native-maps

- cd android && gradlew clean and I get error;
  not delete ..\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\build.gradle and then I was delete this file
- Finally When I want to generate apk from react-native I get this errors

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-maps.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-maps:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Comment: Error occurred depending on package @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation. I solved the problem updating to this package